# IRC "The nickname <nick> is already in use on asimov.freenode.net"

Tags: irc

I don't use IRC much but for some tools it's the main support channel.

Some years ago I managed to work out how to register and claim my nickname, and joined the couple of channels I was interested in on Freenode.net

Now I'm trying to join a new channel, also on freenode.net

It gives me a nickname like `someone-`.

I have identified myself with `/msg NickServ identify anentropic <password>` and can join the channel... but I join as `someone-` instead of `anentropic`.

If I do `/nick anentropic` it complains that:
`The nickname anentropic is already in use on asimov.freenode.net`

Well yeah, that's me. I have identified myself as that nick, using my password.

How do I actually join the new channel as the nickname I have registered and identified myself as?

Comment: Under Libera IRC I notice the same thing. I executed: `msg NickServ RELEASE yournick` and: `/msg NickServ REGAIN yournick`. See: https://libera.chat/guides/faq#why-is-my-nickname-in-use

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Freenode considers nicknames and accounts to be mostly separate. You don't identify to a nickname: you identify to an account, and that account optionally lets you reclaim a nickname. (This is not universal across networks, but has always been the case on freenode.) Being logged into the account is enough to gain all ChanServ privileges, but it doesn't directly affect your nickname.

Because nickname usage is unique across the network but account usage isn't, this lets you have several clients, with different nicknames – e.g. anentropic|work, anentropic[home], anentropic_mobile – to log in to the same account and have the same privileges.

So what you're seeing is a *second* connection by (presumably) your another IRC client. You can:

- figure out where it comes from (is it yours? is it also identified to your account according to `/whois`?)
- /msg it and ask nicely for the nickname (perhaps you'll receive your own message in a forgotten IRC app)
- kick it off and reclaim the nickname (`/msg nickserv regain anentropic`)
- ignore it and use a nickname like `anentropic2` for the time being

Comment: I just worked it out and it was basically this. I'm using Linkinus client. For whatever reason I had ended up with two connections, one grouped as 'Freenode' and another grouped as 'Freenode.net'. I was identified as `anentropic` in both but it seems I can only assume the nick in one at a time. Disconnecting one allowed me to assume the nick in the other and join the channel with that nick.

Comment: The **ERC** client required `M-x list-processes` and manually deleting stale irc.freenode.net:6667 connections after forcibly interrupting a wedged Emacs which probably confused **ERC**.